# ajax stopped working when not logged in?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Have had an autocomplete field working for months but has stopped working when not logged in? Not sure when but within the last few days or week (not updated wordpress recently).

already have;
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_schools', 'filter_schools');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_schools', 'filter_schools');

in functions.php and there are no errors anywhere.

response i get when not logged in is;
from safari...
*Request URL:http://www.payingforit.org.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?term=holywe&action=filter_schools&postType=school
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found*

any help welcome ! Dc.

jquery code

```
 $( "#userSelectedSchool" ).bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {

                $.getJSON( "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", {


            term: extractLast( request.term ), action: 'filter_schools', postType: 'school'
            }, response );

            dataToBeSent = {
                term: extractLast( request.term ), action: 'filter_schools', postType: 'school'
            }

            console.log(request.term);

        }, select: function( event, ui ) {

            var terms = split( this.value );
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push( ui.item.id );
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end // ui.item.label
            terms.push( "" );
            this.value = ui.item.label;

            $('input[name=userSchool]').val(ui.item.urn)

            return false;

        }, open: function() { $('.ui-menu').width(300) }

});
```

function in functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_schools', 'filter_schools');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_schools', 'filter_schools');

function filter_schools(){
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $str = $_GET['term'];
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $postType = $_POST['postType'];

    $finalArgs =  array (
        'posts_per_page'=>5,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'school'
    );

    $searchSchools = new WP_Query( $finalArgs );
    $mypostids = $wpdb->get_col("select ID from $wpdb->posts where post_title LIKE '".$str."%' ");

    $args = array(
        'post__in'=> $mypostids,
        'post_type'=>'school',
        'orderby'=>'title',
        'order'=>'asc'
    );

    $res = new WP_Query($args);
    while( $res->have_posts() ) : $res->the_post();

        global $post;

        $EstablishmentNumber = get_post_meta($post->ID,'EstablishmentNumber', true);
        $URN = get_post_meta($post->ID,'URN', true);
        $add = get_post_meta($post->ID,'address', true);

        $schl = array('post_id'=>$post->ID,'id'=>$EstablishmentNumber, 'label'=>$post->post_title.', '.$add['town'].' '.$add['postcode'] , 'value'=>$EstablishmentNumber, 'urn'=>$URN );
        $matchedSchools[] = $schl;

    endwhile;

    echo json_encode($matchedSchools);
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** I've kept my original answer below, however, I'm not sure what I was thinking... You should *never* need to trigger `do_action( 'wp_ajax...' )`.

While I can't be sure what the issue is, is the code in the question is roughly ok (I think `$_POST` should be `$_GET` with `.getJSON`).

---

Try putting this at the top...

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']=='filter_schools'):
        do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
        do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
endif;
```

I think WordPress does not automatically do ajax actions for users not logged-in. Potentially non-users could things they are not suppose to be able to do.

I would probably change those `$_GET`s & `%_POST`s to `$_REQUEST` too.

Comment: thanks Stephen - made those updates but its still not working when not logged in.

Comment: after messing around a bit it seems the do_action has to come after the add_filter. Working now so thanks stephen...

Comment: I had the same problem with non-admin users. This solution made it, and the order was important in my case too.

Answer (score 3):

Final working code before the filter_schools() function.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']=='filter_teachers'):
    add_action('wp_ajax_filter_teachers', 'filter_teachers');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_teachers', 'filter_teachers');
endif;

if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])):
        do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
        do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
endif;
```

Comment: Daniel, the order shouldn't matter: I have a plug-in where the do_actions are at the top, and add_actions come just before the function being called. Also the add_actions don't need to be inside 'if' statements. But if the above works, then it works!